# +metadataForPersistentStoreOfType failure with NSSQLiteErrorDomain 14

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I need to find the version of the model used in an existing persistent store so I can do a little post-processing after an automatic lightweight migration.

We've got a few devices in a state where we are unable to get the metadata for their persistent stores.

When we initialize the CoreData stack, we use NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's +metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:URL:error: method to get the metadata for the existing persistent store.  Then we check if it's metadata is compatible with the metadata from the current object model to decide if we need to do a migration.  We also pull the model versions from these two sets of metadata--so after the automatic lightweight migration we can do some simple post-processing based on the model versions.

The problem is that +metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:URL:error: is failing and returning nil on some devices.  The error indicates NSSQLiteErrorDomain 14 and "I/O error for database at ".  If I turn on SQLite debugging ("-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1") it doesn't produce much useful info:

```
CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/var/mobile/Applications/65838AB8-2DE4-4B1E-9837-FD252104448B/Library/slide_deck_database_1/StoreContent/persistentStore"
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA
CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database due to an error.
CoreData: error: (14) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/65838AB8-2DE4-4B1E-9837-FD252104448B/Library/slide_deck_database_1/StoreContent/persistentStore.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'
CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database.
metadataForPersistentStoreOfType failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.) (userInfo: {
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
    NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/65838AB8-2DE4-4B1E-9837-FD252104448B/Library/slide_deck_database_1/StoreContent/persistentStore.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'";
})
```

I did find this article on Apple's website, which suggests a potential *source* of the issue: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1809/_index.html  But it doesn't seem to help with my problem.  (It describes a way to migrate a persistent store and change the journaling options... but it assumes I already have an instance of NSPersistentStore, which I don't.  I could add it via the PSC... but that would require migrating it, which defeats the whole purpose--again, because I'm trying to find the version of the existing store before I migrate it.)

One potential complication here is that I'm trying to switch from a UIManagedDocument store to a traditional CoreData stack (we're ditching UIManagedDocument because of a never-ending string of problems, and we understand a standard CoreData stack much better).  In practice this hasn't seemed to have been a problem (until now?) but I thought it might be worth mentioning.

Edit: this is on an iPad (3rd generation) running iOS 7.1.1.

Comment: Are you sure about the URL in the error messages? Is the SQLite file actually named `persistentStore` and not something like `persistentStore.sqlite`?

Comment: Yes.  This was originally created via UIManagedDocument, and this seems to be how it names the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the WAL vs. rollback thing is your problem, do the following:

1. Add the store to an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator using the rollback options as outlined in Technical Q&A 1809. If it can't do so for some other reason, you will get NO as the result of `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options` and a populated error.
2. To read the metadata, get the persistent store you just instantiated from the persistent store coordinator using `persistentStoreForURL:` .
3. At that point you can read the metadata for the store.

Example:

```
NSPersistentStore *store   = nil;
NSError           *error   = nil;
NSDictionary      *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
if (! [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                        configuration:nil
                                        URL:[self storeURL]
                                        options:options
                                        error:&error]) {
    [self presentError:error];
}

store = [persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:[self storeURL]];
// read something out of the metadata. 
id metaDataValue = [[store metadata] valueForKey: NSStoreUUIDKey];
```

You don't need to migrate it. You don't even need to keep that persistent store coordinator around. You can dispose of it as soon as you're done reading the metadata values.

Again, this somewhat assumes that your problem is the WAL vs. rollback SQLite store that is described in QA1809. Given the error that you are seeing any number of things could be the cause. For example, the store could have been previously corrupted by a borked write operation.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Just a note: this *mostly* works.  I get an error "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store", but the metadata for the current version of the store is contained in the userInfo of the NSError, under the "metadata" key.  So I'm at least able to look at the metadata, figure out the store version.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to rethink your current migration process. You mentioned before that you want to perform some post-migration actions based on the pre-migration model version. You may want to consider implementing your own migration manager, or using the userInfo dictionaries to aid in migration. Ultimately, if you have these kinds of version-dependant post migration steps you are going to see more of these incompatibility errors.

Comment: @NicholasHart you may find this thread interesting: https://devforums.apple.com/message/944157#944157